# RxJava 2 Getting Started: serially execute tasks. `andThen` or `defer`?

Tags: rx-java2

I want to run two steps in RxJava serially. I want step 1 to finish before step 2 starts like:

```
step 1: start
step 1: finish
step 2: start
step 2: finish
```

I'm trying different API variations and RxJava is running my two steps in parallel, which is not the behavior that I want:

```
step 1: start
step 2: start
step 2: finish
step 1: finish
```

In the code sample below I try both `andThen` and `defer` and I get parallel execution. How can I fix this so that one step executes after successful completion of the other?

The method name `andThen` implies sequential serial execution. The method `defer` takes a function that produces another Completable which is the method signature that I would expect for the serial task execution that I want. Neither give me the result that I want.

Do I need to convert to Observable/Flowable? Or can I chain two steps with Completable?

```
public class RxStep1Then2 {
    public static Completable simulateCompletable(ScheduledExecutorService es, String msg, int msDelay) {
        System.out.println(String.format("%s: start", msg));

        ScheduledFuture<?> future = es.schedule(() -> {
            System.out.println(String.format("%s: finish", msg));
        }, msDelay, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

        return Completable.fromFuture(future);
    }

    public static void rxMain(ScheduledExecutorService es) {
//        Completable c = simulateCompletable(es, "step 1", 1000)
//                .andThen(simulateCompletable(es, "step 2", 500));

        Completable c = simulateCompletable(es, "step 1", 1000)
                .defer(() -> simulateCompletable(es, "step 2", 500));

        c.blockingAwait();
        System.out.println("blockingAwait done");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ScheduledExecutorService es = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(5);
        System.out.println("Started ExecutorService.");

        rxMain(es);

        es.shutdown();
        es.awaitTermination(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
        System.out.println("Shutdown ExecutorService. Done.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The parallel execution happens because your `simulateCompletable` starts the tasks before the `Completable`s are even created. You could use a delayed `Completable` directly:

```
Completable.fromAction(() -> System.out.println("First"))
    .delay(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .andThen(Completable.fromAction(() -> System.out.println("Second")))
    .blockingAwait();
```

Note that

```
Completable c = simulateCompletable(es, "step 1", 1000)
            .defer(() -> simulateCompletable(es, "step 2", 500));
```

does not chain any operation because `defer` is a static factory method that creates an independent `Completable`; the first `simulateCompletable`'s `Completable` is simply lost.

Comment: I know that `simulateCompletable` starts the tasks. I was hoping the API offered some kind of variant of `andThen` that took a lambda so the second task doesn't get started until the first task completes. I can't find any such API. Also, I don't want to add any delays to this.

Comment: Use `.andThen(Completable.defer(() -> simulateCompletable()))`?

Comment: `andThen(Completable.defer(() -> ...)` fixed it! Thank you!